# Can I input a number in scientific notation?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to input a large number by scientific notation, for example of distance to sun.

`distance = float(input("distance to sun?:"))`

I tried to enter 1.471*10**11 and 1.471e11, but both said "could not convert string to float"
Do I have to type the multiple "0"? Thanks for answering in advance.

Comment: It works for me, `1.471e11` prints as `147100000000.0` - what version of python are you using?

Comment: You are right. It now works..... Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you made a typo first time around.